# Does anyone has a good code example/ library which can perform large file (5GB) PUT operation via S3 presigned URL?

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3

Our Python server will generate a `put_object` presigned URL, and pass it to our Java Android app.

Our Java Android app will then perform PUT operation, using the given resigned URL. The file content can be up to 5GB. (Note: single PUT request for resigned URL can support up to 5GB file size)

Here's the simple code example, in Python.

```
###############
# PRESIGNED URL
###############
url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='put_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': bucket_name, 
        'Key': key_name
    },
    ExpiresIn=3600
)


##################
# GET FILE CONTENT (Should be rewritten in Java, streaming way)
##################
with open(file_name, 'rb') as object_file:
    body = object_file.read()
object_file.close()


#####
# PUT (Should be rewritten in Java, streaming way)
#####
response = requests.put(url, data=body)
```

The given example is not entirely correct if we are gonna to deal with file as large as 5GB.

Reading entire 5GB content into Android device memory, before sending it as single string body, will cause OutOfMemoryException.

I try to search for on how to perform Java PUT operation, in "streaming" way (Using `InputStream` and `OutputStream`) but couldn't find any good example.

Does anyone know how to perform PUT operation for large file, without causing OutOfMemoryException?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably want a multipart upload https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateMultipartUpload.html

Comment: a single `put_object` presigned url will suit to our purpose, as AWS has stated a single `put_object` presigned url request, server can support up to 5GB data. The question is back to client side, on how are we gonna to pass the 5GB data to the presigned url, without going OutOfMemory at client side.

Comment: Break the data up into chunks, load each chunk into memory one at a time, and send via multipart upload. Make the chunks as small as you need to remain within the memory bounds.